# Where is an object instance stored?

Tags: c#-4.0

Is an object stored in the heap when it is an a class instance variable, and in the stack when it's a function variable? Is that correct?

Comment: Where an object is stored is an implementation detail.  Rely on it at your own peril.

Comment: @cHao: Indeed. I don't know about .Net's engine, but Google's V8 JavaScript engine (JavaScript being another garbage-collected environment) is smart enough to do static analysis on the code and identify where objects are only ever used within the function and then released -- and put them on the stack so they get reclaimed immediately upon return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References are stored on stack(Not in all case though)

**Note:** Only for local variables. For instance and class variables, they are part of the object, hence, on the heap.

While Objects are stored on heap.

- Class objects, including method code and static fields: heap.
- Objects, including instance fields: heap.
- Local variables and calls to methods: stack

Comment: very true..so it means all of them will be stored in a heap

Comment: Nope.  There are some oddities regarding value types (which are still objects, but can often be found on the stack).

Comment: *"References are stored on stack"* Not necessarily. What about references in object properties? Those will be on the heap, too. References **in local variables in functions** are probably on the stack.

Comment: I said it in general...Look the second point...I think you are referring to instance fields.

Comment: @ShashankKadne: Regardless the bullet points, the opening sentence is just plain wrong.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: RE: references in local variables: i'm not sure there's a requirement that they be on the stack.  I can imagine a runtime without a stack...the specs may allow for it as well.  I ought to implement one just to blow people's minds :P

Comment: @cHao: I can't see a runtime without *any* stack. You need somewhere to put return addresses. I can see one where you don't use the stack for locals (though I think it would be inefficient). But that's an esoteric implementation detail, off-topic for the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:  I wouldn't say "no" stack, really.  Just not a designated area called "the stack".  Imagine call frames in a linked list, allocated from the same memory used for the heap.  Yeah, it's a bit off topic, and a bit esoteric.  I'm bored.  :)

Comment: @cHao: Sure, I can see that. (And we don't know that that isn't what some engines do. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Stack is a memory place where the methods and the local variables are stored.

Heap is a memory place where the objects and its instance variable are stored.

Now Instance variables are any variables, without "static" field modifier, that are defined within the class body and outside any class's methods body.

Instance variables are in scope as long as their enclosing object is in scope. An instance variable is a part of the object that contains it and cannot live independently of it.

Hope so it will clear your concepts.

Comment: Didn't clear up mine.  It seems to half-answer everything but the actual question.

Comment: The part that was actually in the question?  :P  You've kinda danced all around it, and drawn all sorts of pretty dots, but you haven't really bothered to connect them in a way that truly answers the question that was asked.